# Is it insecure to have your Google Analytics tag visible publicly?

Tags: google-analytics, security, jekyll

I just started adding Google Analytics to my GitHub Pages site, which calls for putting it in the `_config.yml` file. Is it insecure to keep the `_config.yml` file in my public GitHub repository, or is it ok to keep it uploaded there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics tags are already public (very public, in fact), so there's no need to keep it secret.

Since you're using Jekyll, the Google Analytics tag that you put in `_config.yml` will be included in the source code of every page on your compiled website anyways. This is how Google Analytics is able to track everything.

In short, there is nothing insecure about this and no need to worry. It's a public number.